How to include groups with zero counts in a delay quantification query in MySQL 5.5?
I am using MySQL 5.5 and have the following table and data
create temporary table test (
    t_source float, -- generating time; seconds from midnight
    t_received float, -- receiving time; seconds from midnight
    delay float -- t_received - t_source
);

insert into test (t_source, t_received, delay) values
(713.27, 714.61, 1.34),
(2791.81, 2797.09, 5.28),
(94.98, 98.01, 3.03),
(3577.35, 3580.01, 2.66),
(3202.63, 3207.82, 5.19),
(1696.04, 1701.94, 5.9),
(1827.46, 1833.33, 5.87),
(395.78, 400.97, 5.19),
(1102.89, 1105.91, 3.02),
(1598.06, 1602.77, 4.71),
(1662.32, 1667.06, 4.74),
(1532.28, 1533.99, 1.71),
(2488.77, 2489.82, 1.05),
(186.59, 190.34, 3.75),
(2875.11, 2879.48, 4.37),
(1796.25, 1801.35, 5.1),
(2989.3, 2994.22, 4.92),
(1084.44, 1085.45, 1.01),
(2668.18, 2669.23, 1.05),
(2632.22, 2636.42, 4.2);

When I perform the following query:
select t_received, @chid := floor(t_received / 300) chunk_id, count(*) as number, max(delay) as max_delay
from test
group by chunk_id;

I get the following result:



t_received
chunk_id
number
max_delay




98.01
0
2
3.75


400.97
1
1
5.19


714.61
2
1
1.34


1105.91
3
2
3.02


1701.94
5
4
5.9


1833.33
6
2
5.87


2489.82
8
3
4.2


2797.09
9
3
5.28


3207.82
10
1
5.19


3580.01
11
1
2.66



The issue is that some chunk_ids are missing when there are no records in those ranges. I want to include all possible chunk_ids (e.g., 0 to the maximum chunk_id), and for those without any records.
Desired Output
I want the result to include rows with 0 count like this:



t_received
chunk_id
number
max_delay




98.01
0
2
3.75


400.97
1
1
5.19


714.61
2
1
1.34


1105.91
3
2
3.02



4
0
0


1701.94
5
4
5.9


1833.33
6
2
5.87



7
0
0


2489.82
8
3
4.2


2797.09
9
3
5.28


3207.82
10
1
5.19


3580.01
11
1
2.66



How can I include the missing chunk_ids in my query?

The easiest way is probably the same as for filling gaps in dates: have a table of possible chunks and do a left join on that lookup table.

Use static or dynamically generated table with complete chunks list.

Note that MySQL 5.5 is long past end of life.  Treat it as extremely insecure and upgrade as soon as you can

select test.t_received,
       t3.chunk_id,
       count(*) as number,
       max(test.delay) as max_delay
from (
  SELECT @chunk_id := @chunk_id + 1 AS chunk_id
  FROM (SELECT @chunk_id := FLOOR(MIN(t_received) / 300) - 1
        FROM test) t1
  JOIN  (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(t_received) / 300) AS stop
        FROM test) t2
  JOIN test
  WHERE @chunk_id < t2.stop
) t3
LEFT JOIN test ON t3.chunk_id = floor(test.t_received / 300)
group by chunk_id;




t_received
chunk_id
number
max_delay




98.01
0
2
3.75


400.97
1
1
5.19


714.61
2
1
1.34


1105.91
3
2
3.02


null
4
1
null


1701.94
5
4
5.9


1833.33
6
2
5.87


null
7
1
null


2489.82
8
3
4.2


2797.09
9
3
5.28


3207.82
10
1
5.19


3580.01
11
1
2.66



step-by-step fiddle
PS. temporary table cannot be used more than once in the query, so static source table is used.
PPS. Adjist number for non-existent chunks by yourself.
PPPS. t_received is randomly selected value when more than one row per chunk exists. Add MIN() or MAX() for to fix.

t_received is not important and can be removed from the query. Thank you for your approach, but I prefer to use a temporary table composed of other tables rather than creating static tables and deleting them after the calculation. I think I will go with a table that include all the possible chunk_ids. I would prefer to avoid this, but I believe it is the most suitable solution in my case.

@JoseÁngeldePascualViciana You may use dynamically generated chunks table based on any system table which contains sufficient amount of rows.
